# Samba shares read only after switch from Debian to Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, cifs

I've bought a new computer and thats why I switched to Ubuntu. Debian and new hardware don't mix...

I have some smb shares that I've put in my fstab.

```
//192.168.0.2/foo        /media/foo    cifs    credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials  0      0
```

The mount as such works fine but I have read only rights. I didn't change anything in my smb.conf on the server. Plus when I mount a folder manually in the file browser by clicking "Other Location" and going on my server via smb://IP and right click the folder and choose "mount" it works with all permissions? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why that line in fstab worked in Debian and not Ubuntu but I would suggest changing it to this:

```
//192.168.0.2/foo /media/foo cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=1000  0      0
```

1000 is your uid number. To verify that run this command and change fstab as required:

```
id
```

Note: Since this is Linux-to-Linux you may need another option: nounix. So the fstab line would be:

```
//192.168.0.2/foo /media/foo cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,nounix  0      0
```